# Reverse Check digit algorithm

Tags: reverse-engineering

I am trying to reverse engineer an algorithm used to generate a check digit.

Numbers are 8 digits long and the last digit is the check digit. I have thousands of valid numbers to test it on.

I have try several standard algorithm but come up with nothing

Here is some examples of valid numbers:

```
3482145 6
3482146 4
3482147 2
3482148 3
3482149 9
3482150 1
3482151 0
3482152 8
3482153 6
3482154 4
3482155 2
3482156 3
3482157 9
3482158 7
3482159 5
3482160 8
3482161 6
```

Is it possible to calculate this? Any ideas?

Comment: "I have try several standard algorithm" Please list them and how you decided to exclude them. Did you consider narrow CRCs?

Answer (score 1):

The amount of data you provided is insufficient to adequately assess the algo. The only thing I can see right now is that the sequence 64239xx8 is repeated twice, and the last digit is also 6.

Not an actual answer, I`m afraid, but StackOverflow does not yet allow me to leave comments.

Comment: Ah thank you for trying, I already figured it out, its an mod(10 or 11) algorithm with some edit which i cannot found out, but i did notice that if the code increase by 1, the check digit will follow this sequence : 8 6 4 2 3 9 7 5 3 1 0;

Answer (score -1):

```
The algorithm is this:
coef[]={4,2,1,6,3,7,9}
modulus 11
Case 10->0
Case 0->3
```